# why do bindAll in backbone.js views?

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

In backbone's [todo demo](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/examples/todos/index.html) the code has a few spots where `_.bindAll(this,...)` is used. Specifically it's used in the `initialize` function of both views. As far as I can tell it's necessary to do the following:

```
this.$('.todo-content').text(content);
```

But why would one want to do the above, when one can do:

```
$('.todo-content').text(content);
```

?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`this.$` limits jQuery's context to the view's element, so operations are quicker.

Additionaly, `this.$('.todo-item')`  won't find your elements with `todo-item` class outside your view's element.

Answer (score 93):

`_.bindAll( this, ... )` is necessary not only for `this.$( selector ).doSomething()` but generally to be sure that `this` in your view's method is always pointing to the view itself.

For example, if we want to refresh our view when the model changes, we bind the view's `render` method to the model's `change` event:

```
initialize: function() {
    this.model.bind( 'change', this.render );
},
```

Without `_.bindAll( this, 'render' )`, when the model changes `this` in `render` will be pointing to the *model*, not to the view, so we won't have neither `this.el` nor `this.$` or any other view's properties available.

Answer (score 59):

As of Backbone 0.5.2, it's no longer necessary to use _.bindAll(this...) in your views to set the context of the "bind" callback functions, as you can now pass a 3rd argument to bind() that will set the context (i.e. "this") of the callback.

For example:

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    this.model.bind('change', this.render, this);
  },
  render: function(){
    // "this" is correctly set to the instance of MyView
  }
});
```

Comment: The line "this.model.bind('change', this.render, this)" just makes my head spin >.<

Comment: Try coffeescript and its => operator.

Comment: Do notice that `this.bind` (or `this.model.bind`) do a completely different thing than `_.bind`. Took me a while to realize.

Comment: @JonatanLittke right, the backbone binds are an alias for 'on'

Comment: this is not recommended - it is more recommended to use this.listenTo(this.model,'change:id',this.render); because then the listeners will be removed when you destroy the view