# Bind events on body element from inside a view

Tags: backbone.js

Is it possible to bind events on body element inside a view?

For example this doesn't work

```
Backbone.View.extend({
  el : "#some element here",
  events : {
    "mouseup body" : "onMouseUp"
  }
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think is not possible.

[Backbone.View.events](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1224) uses internally [this.$el.delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) which internally uses [CSS selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors) which looks like [doesn't support *upwards* selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector).

You can instead add a `position: absolute` div into your `el` DOM element and make it transparent and fullscreen it. And then capture events from there.

Answer (score 1):

Well I think I found a working solution!

In the initialize function I do

```
$('body').bind('mouseup', this.onMouseUp);
```

<strike>And it works like charm! :)</strike>

**EDIT**

Actually there is a big problem with that! The this is bind on the body and not on the view. So I have a parameter "pressed" and when I access it with this.pressed it tries to find it in the body....

**EDIT**

The solution I found to the problem above is to pass in the bind parameters a reference to this like:

```
$('body').bind('mouseup',{thisView : this}, this.onMouseUp);
```

And now it works like charm :P

Comment: still I think my answer match your question _"Is it possible ..."_ ;)

Comment: Well you're right it is not possible to have a "mouseup body" : "method here" in a view with different el

Comment: @fguillen Can you see my edited answer. How should I fix this?

Comment: the eternal _JS context dilema_ :).. you can fix this in different approachs. 1) [the one you have found](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/setting-a-context-in-fn-bind), 2) [using jQuery.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy), 3) [using Underscore.bindAll](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6396224/316700), 4) (sure there are more)

Comment: cool, I understand proxy but how can I use the bindAll? What is the most elegant way?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10271/discussion-between-chchrist-and-fguillen)