# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toJSON' of undefined

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I am getting following error in Backbone.JS,

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method '**toJSON**' of undefined.

Here is the code for model and View,

```
 <script src="js/underscore.js"></script>
     <script src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/backbone.js"></script>

    var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
            defaults:{
                name:"niran",
                age:20
            },
            validate:function(attr){
                if(attr.age <0){
                    return "should be greater than 0";
                }
            }
        }
    )

    var PhotoSearch = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName:"li",
        initialize:function(){
            console.log(this.model)
            this.render();
        },

        template:_.template("<%= name %>(<%= age %>"),

        render:function(){
            this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        }
    });
       var p = new Person();
    var ps = new PhotoSearch({model:p});
```

any idea on this

Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

According to the Backbone.js documentation ( http://backbonejs.org/ ), you need [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var PhotoSearch = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName:"li",
        initialize:function(){
            _.bindAll(this, "render");
            console.log(this.model)
            this.render();
        },

        template:_.template("<%= name %>(<%= age %>"),

        render:function(){
            this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        }
    });
```

You're missing a call to `_.bindAll(this, "render");` Without this call, `this` will not be set to the context of the view, which means that `.model` will be undefined.

You could also use `_.bindAll(this);` to bind all methods.

[why do bindAll in backbone.js views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079055/why-do-bindall-in-backbone-js-views)

Comment: Can you put `console.log(this)` inside of `render()` and see what `this` actually is? I still think it could be that `this` is not the view, which is why you're getting the error.

Comment: child {cid: "view2", model: child, options: Object, $el: e.fn.e.init[1], el: <li>}      This the output i got

Comment: try `this.$el.html(this.template(model.toJSON()));` so you're not using `this` in the call. What happens?

Comment: No luck! But I found one thing, I am declaring variable in chrome console, during that time this error is coming up. However if same variable declared in the html file it works fine! But for the VIEW this is failing and for Backbone.MODEL.extend works fine in chrome console. Strange isn't it!

Comment: Hmmm, not sure what's going on here I'm afraid :(

Comment: Cheers for the offer, but I'm afraid I can't really help any further, as I've tried all the suggestions which I thought would help.