# Can't access Backbone View within a view consistently

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

I'm trying to create a master view/controller for a Backbone project, and I'm having troubles accessing the views within the view properly. Here's the code:

```
var Controller = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.characterView = new CharacterView({model: character});
        this.encounterView = new EncounterView({collection: encounter});
        this.characterView.$el.on('click', '.attack', this.charAttack);
    },
    charAttack: function() {
        console.log(this.characterView);
    },
    render: function() {
        this.encounterView.render();
        this.characterView.render();
        console.log(this.characterView.model.toJSON());
    }
});

var controller = new Controller();
controller.render();
```

The `this.characterView` in charAttack is undefined whereas in the render function, it uses the right object. I'm not sure why render can access this.characterView, but charAttack can't. Any help to understand this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `this.characterView.$el.on('click', '.attack', this.charAttack);` is a strange thing to be doing in a Backbone app. That would normally be handled through `characterView`'s `events` map and the actually attacking logic would probably be a method on the character model which would broadcast any state changes (such as death from losing too many HP) through events.

Comment: If I have a characterView and an encounterView (with the monsters), how would I access a model from a collection in encounterView from characterView? i.e. Character clicks attack, prompts charAttack which shows buttons on monsters, click on the button, and charAttack uses that model and it's own model to process the combat logic. Here's the repo if it helps: https://github.com/mmerkes/into_the_shadow

Comment: Actually, wouldn't the "attack" button be part of the encounter view? And presumably the encounter view would know who was involved in the encounter.

Comment: Perhaps, but I'm trying to keep the action buttons on the characterView (which is aside from the encounterView) so that once I have more actions (use item, cast spell, etc) that come up during your turn, the actions would dictate what views/models/collections are affected. For this reason, I created the controller/master view so that I could access both views within it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add [_.bindAll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079055/why-do-bindall-in-backbone-js-views) to your initialize function:

```
initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this); // assuming Underscore < 1.5.0
    this.characterView = new CharacterView({model: character});
    this.encounterView = new EncounterView({collection: encounter});
    this.characterView.$el.on('click', '.attack', this.charAttack);
},
```

This ensures that `this` inside the view functions (including `charAttack`) always refers to the view.

---

To verify if you're having this problem try this in Chrome with the console open:

```
charAttack: function() {
    debugger;
    console.log(this.characterView);
},
```

Then in the console type this and see if it's bound to `window` or another variable.

Comment: `_.bindAll` without method names is deprecated since Underscore 1.5.0 http://underscorejs.org/#changelog

Comment: `_.bindAll(this, 'charAttack');` would do the trick for nearly all versions of Underscore, but to each his own.

Comment: `_.bindAll(this, 'charAttack');` did the trick. And definitely right on the lack of methods names.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access `this` elements unless you have instanted your Object.

```
var ModController = function(){
    var characterView;
    var encounterView;

    var Controller = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function() {
            characterView = new CharacterView({model: character});
            encounterView = new EncounterView({collection: encounter});
            this.characterView.$el.on('click', '.attack', this.charAttack);
        },
        charAttack: function() {
            console.log(characterView);
        },
        render: function() {
            encounterView.render();
            characterView.render();
            console.log(this.characterView.model.toJSON());
        } 
    });

    return new Controller();

}

var myController = new ModController(); 
myController.render();
```

So I beleave that [Revealing Pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript) could solve you problem.

Comment: Sure global variable is not a good idea, you need to combine for example a Revealing Pattern to restrict the scope of this variables.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the revealing pattern. It looks interesting.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few points to note:

1. 1 you are using jQuery to bind DOM events, when in fact backbone
   provides a more elegant and useful mechanism to achieve the same
   goal. Take a look at [backbone's event hash can be found here](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents).
2. You are calling `controller.charAttack` from inside an event
   handler. When you do this, the property `this` within
   `controller.charAttack` will not point to 'controller', most likely
   it will point to 'window'.

There are many ways to get around the problem. Because you are responding to a click event, you could instead bind your event handlers using backbone's events property. Remove the line `this.characterView.$el…` and add this new property (typically before the `initialise` declaration:

```
events: {
  'click .attack' : 'charAttack'
},
```

Comment: I tried adding the above code, and the js console logged that charAttack was not defined.

Comment: My mistake, sorry. I forgot to add quotes around 'charAttack'. I see you've selected an answer that would work. Glad to hear you got past your difficulty.For others coming to the question, the `events:{}` hash as a property of a view is the standard way to set up responses to DOM events. It's a nice, declarative syntax and behind the scenes backbone will set up the event binding for you.